# Aggressive C-g config

Tags: key-bindings, quitting

Is there a way to configure `C-g` (or some other key?) to not be usable as normal input in any context, part of a key binding, etc, and instead have it quit in more contexts? e.g. I'd like `C-x C-g` to quit immediately (instead of saying `C-x C-g` is undefined, then quitting)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're actually trying to do. Can you explain how this causes a problem? In what context does it make any difference whether or not this message is printed?

Answer (score 1):

```el
(advice-add #'undefined :override #'keyboard-quit)
```

It is a hack.

Answer (score 0):

`C-g` isn't treated specially. Any undefined key will prompt the message "key is undefined". For example, with `emacs -Q`, `C-c C-g` and `C-c a` both give you that message.

If you really need to change this behaviour, you can define `C-g` explicitly:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-g") 'keyboard-quit)
```

For what you're asking, you'll need to do this for every prefix key, and new prefix keys can be created by you, or by add-on packages. Which means I don't think there's a straightforward way to impose this globally.

You might have better success if you can explain why this behaviour is a problem for you; then we might be able to find a more general solution.